# What does `#!foobar!#` notation mean in this `rCharts` adaptation?

Tags: javascript, html, r, dygraphs, rcharts

I am trying to recreate an `rCharts`-based, interactive `dygraphs` chart by running the `code.R` from this [timelyportfolio/rCharts_dygraphs GitHub repository.](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts_dygraphs/blob/gh-pages/code.R)

Compared to [**what it should look like**](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/research_scholar/), my chart however doesn't render completely:

[image]

By comparing html page sources, I think the problem is that the `date` array hasn't evaluated properly:

> "date": [ "#! new Date(252374400000)!#", "#! new Date(283910400000)!#", .... ]

Corresponding [`R` source code snippet](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts_dygraphs/blob/gh-pages/code.R#L18-L22) 
contains `#!` annotation unfamiliar to me:

```
fama.df$date <- paste0(
  "#! new Date(",
  as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste0(fama.df$year,"-12-31"))) * 1000,
  ")!#"
)
```

What is the background for this annotation and how can I fix this?

Comment: The background for the `#!... !#` annotation is to tag an object as a javascript literal so that it is not transformed into a string during conversion to JSON. Can you post the entire code that you were trying to evaluate so that it is clearer to me what exactly you were trying?

Comment: Thanks @Ramnath , the entire code is in the first link of the post. That repository contains all the relevant files, I've just copy-pasted and run entire `code.R`, while having `chart.html`, `config.yml`, `dygraph-combined.js` and `lodash.js` copied in the same working directory.

Comment: @Ramnath, I've just noticed [in these lines of `rCharts` source](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/e917d6e93334b111e9cdbe3d5607636ab5832161/R/toJSON.R#L106-L108) that `toObj` function has been commented out and replaced. Now note the difference: `x <- paste0("#! new Date(", as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste0(2011,"-12-31"))) * 1000, ")!#"); gsub('\"#!(.*?)!#\"', "\\1", x); gsub('#!(.*)!#', "\\1", x)`. Is this source edit the cause? @timelyportfolio published the original code in autumn 2013.

Comment: It is def related to that piece of code, but I am not sure why it broke. Can you file this as an issue on github>

Comment: @Ramnath, filed as https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was a [newer implementation of rCharts](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts/tree/dimple_layer/).  Try installing from that branch, but after running be sure to get current again.  I was playing around with how to handle dates like googleVis.

```
require(devtools)
install_github("rCharts","timelyportfolio",ref="dimple_layer")
```

Also, you will need to do like in the updated [code.R](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts_dygraphs/blob/gh-pages/code.R)

```
dy1$setTemplate(afterScript = "<script></script>"
```

You might notice that dygraphs is not fully developed.  We are starting an rChartsExtra to house the experiments/alternate libraries.

Comment: thank you, worked. I am very much grateful for the pioneering integration of the `R` and `js` worlds in your and @Ramnath repositories - great learning material